# TDBGrid showing default Context popup menu instead of custom menu

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have written code to assign my custom PopUpMenu to a DBGrid component. These changes have been done in dfm file:

```
object myGrid: TDBGrid
..................
PopupMenu = myPopUp
..................
end

object myPopUp: TPopupMenu
    Left = 528
    Top = 176
    object mnuFillDown: TMenuItem
      Action = actionFillDown
    end 
  end

object actionFillDown: TAction
  Caption = 'Fill Down'
  ShortCut = 16453
  OnExecute = actionFillDownExecute
end
```

But somehow the menu shown is default context menu, and not my custom menu. How should I turn off the default context menu and use the custom menu?

Comment: You better let the IDE manage the `.dfm` files as it is designed to do so. Do not edit the `.dfm` files yourself!.

Comment: Sorry, if I misunderstood you regarding editing the .dfm yourself. Anyway I can not reproduce your problem in Delphi-7. Please provide exact steps and/or a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: "I have written code to assign my custom PopUpMenu to a DBGrid component". What code? Do not try to temper with the dfm manually, unless you know exactly what you are doing. Open a fresh project and try to replicate.

Answer (score 1):

The key factor to have the DBGrid to show your popup menu is that you set the DBGrids  `PopupMenu` property to your popup menu. It looks like you have done this based on

```
object myGrid: TDBGrid
..................
PopupMenu = myPopUp
..................
end
```

although it is not correctly indented. Since it still doesn't popup for you, please verify that this is properly set. Look at my example below how the assignment is indented in relation to the TDBGrid object.

This seems to be your error (assuming `actionFillDownExecute` is the `OnExecute` event handler for the `TAction actionFillDown`):

```
object myPopUp: TPopupMenu
  Left = 528
  Top = 176
  object mnuFillDown: TMenuItem
    Action = actionFillDownExecute
  end 
end
```

You can not assign an event handler to a `TMenuItem.Action` property, which expects a `TAction` (or descendant). The above does not compile!

Instead you should have the `TAction` `actionFillDown` assigned to the menu items `Action`property and assign the `actionFillDownExecute` procedure to the OnExecute event of action.

Here's the .dfm of a testproject:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 313
  Top = 142
  Width = 393
  Height = 177
  Caption = 'Form1'
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object DBGrid1: TDBGrid
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 320
    Height = 120
    PopupMenu = myPopup
    TabOrder = 0
    TitleFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    TitleFont.Color = clWindowText
    TitleFont.Height = -11
    TitleFont.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
    TitleFont.Style = []
  end
  object myPopup: TPopupMenu
    Left = 336
    Top = 56
    object FillDown1: TMenuItem
      Action = actFillDown
    end
  end
  object ActionList1: TActionList
    Left = 336
    Top = 24
    object actFillDown: TAction
      Caption = 'Fill Down'
      OnExecute = actFillDownExecute
    end
  end
end
```

And an image of the menu:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my notice. My bad that I didn't post the entire code earlier. Please look at my edited code in the question posted above. Even after having this code, I still see the default context menu popup. Is there a way to find out if some other component on the Form is causing this default popup?

Comment: @jetty Your edit made your question worst. First, do not post fake code (meaning editing directly in the editor here) Copy - paste avoids typing errors. For .dfm files, indentation is the key! As I requested earlier, describe exactly how you are creating the actions in the IDE and linking them with the menu.

Comment: I read that overriding OnContextPopup and setting Handled := True will disable the context menu. But for what component of the DBGrid should I override OnContextPopup?

Comment: @jetty TDBGrid doesn't have an `OnContextPopup` event. Even if it would, setting `Handled := True;` would prevent both the standard menu and your own popup menu from showing. You don't want that. There is still something wrong in your code, but you have not provided sufficient information to analyze. Maybe you should ask yourself what is different in your code compared with my working example.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Delphi XE4. Found that it occurs if an OnDblClick event was assigned to the TDBGrid BEFORE the PopUpComponent was assigned to it. Solution: remove the reference to OnDblClick, run the program, and add the reference to OnDblClick.
Very strange, but it worked for me.